# Do we allow questions like Russian-to-Whatever and Whatever-to-Russian?

Tags: discussion, proposal

English is clearly a favorable language that most people on this QnA are willing to do back and forth. What else should we allow? What languages are disallowed? It is a good question to be copied over to FAQ once it is resolved.

Comment: Whoever down-voted this should explain themselves. I think it is a legitimate question for those who are not familiar with conventions of SE language sites.

Comment: Don't take it so way. Downvotes on meta doesn't mean that the proposal question is unlegitimate. They means that someone disagree with the proposal.

Comment: @lechlukasz: Votes on meta questions should avoid ambiguity by only applying to whether the question is a good one. Agreement and disagreement should be expressed in comments, answers, and voting answers up and down... But yes Askers should also be aware that some people won't consider this distinction and just accept the fact that votes on meta questions are intrinsically ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

No, because this would make this site the any-language site. Russian-to-English and opposite are allowed because this is site about Russian in English (for English-speaking people). For multi-language there is Languages proposal.

If you'd like to ask questions abount German-to-Russian etc., propose site **Russian language and usage in German** etc.

Comment: Where exactly does the "in English" bit come from? I see nothing to that effect in either the proposal or the meta.

Comment: It comes from the fact that StackOverflow, Stack Exchange and Area51 are English-speaking sites. There were a lot of discissions on meta.stackoverflow.com about language policy

Comment: @lechlukasz, “there were” is not a reference. Particular links would be nice.