# Question bodies in other languages

Tags: discussion

Are questions asked in another (third) languages allowed to be asked? Is SE designed to be specifically English-centric (if so, link to relevant blog post or FAQ for those of us not familiar with SE bylaws)?

Here is the example of situation I see it happening. Say there is Spanish-speaking user, who is proficient enough to read English, but not enough to speak/write effectively. If he has Russian language question, the only avenue he might have is to go to general QA site like es.answers.yahoo.com, and deal with no or poor quality answers. Whereas here we have a Russian language-specific site populated by quality answerers, who can either answer the question in that third language (either by another Spanish-speaking SE user, or someone like I, who could communicate in broken Spanish reasonably effectively) or double the question with translation.

**Note:** This question is designed to be different from [What languages should we use for the site](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-languages-should-we-use-for-the-site?cb=1) (which is logically similar, but seem to be focused more on UI language, FAQs, wiki etc.), and from [Do we allow questions like Russian-to-whatever and whatever-to-Russian](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19/do-we-allow-questions-like-russian-to-whatever-and-whatever-to-russian) (as those questions could still be required to be asked in English or Russian which is what I seek to clarify).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What language(s) should we use for the site?](http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-languages-should-we-use-for-the-site)

Comment: What languages should we use for the site has UI and FAQ concerns as a side-note, not the main topic. If you like, you're welcome to add this particular example to my question.

Comment: @kot, Your question asks specifically about Russian and English (which, by the way, seems redundant as per the very idea of this site). Unless you significantly revise and expand the question, it does not strike me as duplicate outside of the title.

Comment: Different people have different ideas about what is common sense, so I felt it would be good to get some sort of consensus on what languages to use that we could go back to.

Comment: Similar questions appeared on German L&U: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/283/is-glu-is-only-language-site-which-allows-translation-questions-from-any-langua